# Нужно выбрать из кафедр ту ,у которой больше всего заявок

Tags: c++, c

Для того,что бы "создать" кафедры ,я написал структуру, а потом ,благодаря ей создал 5 кафедр. 4-я кафедра имеет больше всего заявок(40) (на 2-е значение(10) не обращайте внимание - это кол-во позитивных решений ,оно нигде не используется).Позже все кафедры я поместил в массив,и стал стравнивать кол-во заявок. Но на выходе ,получается ,что у кафедры 5 больше всего заявок ,но это не верно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

/*25 Враховуючи інформацію про винахідницьку діяльність кафедр за три
роки: найменування кафедр, кількість заявок, кількість позитивних рішень,
вивести повідомлення про кафедру з максимальною кількістю заявок.*/

struct Cafedra
{
    char nameofcafedra[20];
    int numofZayav;
    int numofPozitivRish;
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    Cafedra kafedra1{"Kafedra1" , 31 , 7};
    Cafedra kafedra2{ "Kafedra2" , 23 ,15 };
    Cafedra kafedra3{ "Kafedra3" , 39 , 10 };
    Cafedra kafedra4{ "Kafedra4" , 40 , 10 };
    Cafedra kafedra5{ "Kafedra5" , 24 , 10 };
    
    const int size = 5; //Кол-во кафедр
    Cafedra kf[size] = {kafedra1,kafedra2,kafedra3,kafedra4,kafedra5};//Тут у нас все кафедры
    Cafedra NULLL;NULLL.numofZayav = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            if (kf[i].numofZayav > kf[j].numofZayav)
                NULLL = kf[i];

    cout << "У кафедры: " << NULLL.nameofcafedra << "больше всего заявок, а именно: " << NULLL.numofZayav;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Короче,не могу найти максимальное значение в массиве

Comment: У вас в `NULLL` будет одна их тех кафедр, которые сравнивались последними и которая оказалась больше. Последнее такое сравнение — пятой кафедры, вот она и записывается в `NULLL`. Кстати, вообще странный поиск максимального значения за O(N^2)...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте хотя бы так...

```
Cafedra NULLL;
NULLL.numofZayav = kf[0].numofZayav;

for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
    if (kf[i].numofZayav > NULLL.numofZayav)
        NULLL = kf[i];
```

Comment: Да, конечно 0..